# AES Encryption is not working (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt string in Xcode to PHP with AES128 method by using following code:

Xcode

```
- (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256];

    [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString *iv = @"fdsfds85435nfdfs";
    char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];

    [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted    = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, NULL,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength,
                                          buffer, bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

But when I run above coding, following result is not what I expect to be:

```
NSString *key = @"89432hjfsd891787";

NSData *plaintext =  [[@"aaa0000000000000" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey: key];

NSString *mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plaintext encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"mystring %@", mystring);
```

OUTPUT is

> uçó)â½S/èRÅ

What I want it something like that.

> m9FNGM9IiwibWFjIjoiNmJkYzNmZTA5

Comment: BTW, Xcode is just a fancy editor/compiler/debugger. The code in this case is Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: due to a coding error the `keyPtr` is **not set** to the `key` value, it becomes the value of the uninitialized memory.

You get "uçó)â½S/èRÅ" because you try to create a string from the data and there are a couple reasons this will not work.

1. Many data bytes do not map to printable ASCII characters or to any unicode character.
2. A data byte can be 0 (1 in 256 bytes on average will be 0x00) and that is a terminator for a "C" string so the string will be short.

There are two general conventions for encoding data into a string representation:

1. Hex-ascii where each data byte is encoded into two characters 0-9a-f.
2. Base64 where each 3 data data bytes are encoded into 4 ASCII characters.

You are probably looking for Base64 encoding:

```
NSString *mystring = [plaintext base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Other errors in the code:

1. `[key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];` The string may not be ASCII, better to use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Note that the output is not captured.
2. The `keyPtr` is never set to the key value, see above.
3. The key size id specified as 256-bits (32-bytes) but the key is 16 characters, use a key size that matched the key.
4. `char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128]`, an iv size is the block size not the key size: `kCCBlockSizeAES128`.

Comment: By the way, can u help me to post complete coding here?

Comment: Having thought about this I will decline. This is because there are many issues that need to be addressed and would require a having a lot of questions/answers. It you want  a secure implementation get a security domain expert (yes, they will want to be paid; no not me). It you just want to feel secure continue on, that is the usual level of security. Encryption is a component of security, security is not just encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a Base64 encoded string.

```
NSString *mystring = [plaintext base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: But when I change string to "this is testing" return gone to null.